# Enabling"No symbols" mode for layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

How can I enable "No Symbols" for a layer using PyQGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

null_renderer = QgsNullSymbolRenderer()

lyr.setRenderer(null_renderer)

# update map canvas
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

Documentation: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.26/core/QgsNullSymbolRenderer.html